# Двоеточие или точка с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, двоеточие, точка-с-запятой

*На дворе декабрь() окрестность, охваченная снежным саваном, тихо цепенеет.*

Какой знак препинания вы поставите в скобках? Я поставил двоеточие. Объясняя тем, что окрестность охвачена снежным саваном... Из-за того, что на улице декабрь. Однако тест, которой я выполнял, показал мне ошибку. В тесте точка с запятой. Хотя возможен и такой вариант. Но всё же, исходя из смысла, я склоняюсь к двоеточию. Ваше мнение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точка с запятой здесь вполне подходит. Описываются две  ситуации без причинно-следственной связи (погода в декабре не обязательно снежная и морозная).

Comment: Да. ну возможна и так. Все зависит от смысла.

Comment: Выбор двоеточия или точки с запятой - авторское решение, то есть взаимную обусловленность предложений обозначить можно.

Comment: Вот и я об этом. Вот и решай тесты после этого.
____
Из того же теста. Нечаев был скуповат Перов щедр. Поставьте знаки препинания.

Comment: Нечаев был скуповат, Перов щедр. Сравнить: Я был озлоблен, он угрюм. При этом логически выделяется сказуемое. Если в обоих предложениях будем выделять подлежащее, то получится: Нечаев был скуповат, Перов - щедр. Также можно противопоставить два сообщения, если  тексте даются другие противопоставления для этих лиц: Нечаев был скуповат - Перов щедр.

Comment: Начаев был скуповат, Петр - шедр.Я выбрал этот вариант. В тесте был:Нечаев был скуповат, Перов - щедр.

Comment: Без контекста выбрать единственно правильное решение нельзя. Варианты всегда отличаются смысловыми оттенками, и для конкретного текста лучше подходит один из них. Поэтому только смысловое решение дает правильный ответ,  в то время как  все упражнения с подстановками и применением формальных правил далеко не всегда гарантируют нужный результат.

Answer (score 2):

Значения причины во второй части БСП нет, пояснения нет (невозможно вставить "а именно"), дополнения нет. Двоеточие не ставится.
Две относительно самостоятельные части в предложении. После первой можно даже поставить точку. А в БСП - точка с запятой, подчеркивающая смысловую самостоятельность простых предложений в составе сложного.

Comment: Ну почему же? Т.к. на улице декабрь, окрестность охвачена снежным саваном.

Comment: Если бы предложение выглядело так: Окрестность охвачена снежным саваном: на улице декабрь, - тогда да, двоеточие. Причина.
_____
Но декабрь на дворе вовсе не потому, что окрестность охвачена снежным саваном. Расположение частей здесь принципиально важно.

Comment: Да, вовсе не потому, а окрестность охвачена потому, что на дворе декабрь. Т.е. причина тому - декабрь.

Comment: Сравните: "На дворе декабрь: окрестность, охваченная снежным саваном, тихо цепенеет" (на дворе декабрь, потому что цепенеет, - бессмыслица). "На дворе декабрь - окрестность, охваченная снежным саваном, тихо цепенеет" (цепенеет, потому что декабрь). "На дворе декабрь; окрестность, охваченная снежным саваном, тихо цепенеет" (нет причинно-следственной связи).

Comment: Тат, вы сами знаете, тире и двоеточие в этом случае совпадают по функции.

Comment: Всадник крикнул: лошадь понеслась. Всадник крикнул - лошадь понеслась. Где совпадение функций?

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя поставить там точку, разделив таким образом предложение на два? Я бы так и сделала.

Comment: Такое тоже возможно. Но это задание из теста.А там - точка с запятой.  Двоеточие я там объяснял тем, что холода наступили по причине декабря. Т.е. в второй части раскрывается причина того, что говорится в первом предложении.

Comment: При двоеточии в БСП причина находится ВО ВТОРОЙ ЧАСТИ, не в первой. Не декабрь у вас причина, а снег: декабрь, потому что снег. Ср.: "Выйти невозможно: на улице проливной дождь" (основное содержание заключено в первой части, во второй указывается причина). — "На улице проливной дождь — выйти невозможно" (причина указывается в первой части, во второй приводится следствие, вывод, что составляет основу высказывания).

Comment: Да, я знаю. Вот видимо здесь я и ошибся. Почему-то показалось, что причина заключена в первой части.

Comment: Всех иногда клинит. Бывает:)

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Ермаковой. Точка была бы кстати.

Comment: Да, но в тестах точка с запятой.